# User generated item multiple choice field Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-views

I am looking for a way to have a multiple choice field populated with choices made by a user. For example, they could have the following 3 entries: Yes, No, Unsure. I want a way to be translate this to a model.

I understand this can be done with pre-defined options using a CharField, or ChoiceField, but I haven't seen anything with "dynamic" data, such as user-generated data.

Comment: Where is this user-generated data stored?

Comment: so you want user on the front to create a new value (choice value) and then select the  newly created value ? and user can create n numbers of new values ?

Comment: Yes, basically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't use choice fields in this case, because everytime a user creates a new option, you'll have to run a new migration.

Maybe you can create a `UserOption` model and create a new obj everytime a user creates a new option. Then fetch all the options the user has created when he needs to choose between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply user choices to a DB table. However, you could store a user's choices somewhere, such as a User's Profile, and use them in a dynamically constructed form with a ChoiceField to constrain what he can put into a particular database column / model field.

Could be a PITA if he decides to delete a choice and then wants to edit the (now invalid) data in one of his records.